# spark connecting to Phoenix NoSuchMethod Exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I am trying to connect to Phoenix through Spark/Scala to read and write data as a DataFrame. I am following the example on [GitHub](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/tree/master/phoenix-spark) however when I try the very first example **Load as a DataFrame using the Data Source API** I get the below exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put.setWriteToWAL(Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Put;

There are couple of things that are driving me crazy from those examples:

1)The import statement `import org.apache.phoenix.spark._` gives me below exception in my code:

> cannot resolve symbol phoenix

I have included below jars in my sbt

```
"org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-spark" % "4.4.0.2.4.3.0-227" % Provided,
"org.apache.phoenix" % "phoenix-core" % "4.4.0.2.4.3.0-227" % Provided,
```

2) I get the deprecated warning for symbol load.[image]

I googled about that warnign but didn't got any reference and I was not able to find any example of the suggested method. I am not able to find any other good resource which guides on how to connect to Phoenix. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

please use .read instead of load as shown below

```
val df = sparkSession.sqlContext.read
        .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
        .option("zkUrl", "localhost:2181")
        .option("table", "TABLE1").load()
```

Answer (score 1):

Its late to answer but here's what i did to solve a similar problem(Different method not found and deprecation warning):

1.) About the NoSuchMethodError: I took all the jars from hbase installation lib folder and add it to your project .Also add pheonix spark jars .Make sure to use compatible versions of spark and pheonix spark.Spark 2.0+ is compatible with pheonix-spark-4.10+
[maven-central-link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.phoenix/phoenix-spark/4.10.0-HBase-0.98).This resolved the NoSuchMethodError

2.) About the load - The load method has long since been deprecated .Use sqlContext.phoenixTableAsDataFrame.For reference see this [Load as a DataFrame directly using a Configuration object](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/tree/master/phoenix-spark#load-as-a-dataframe-directly-using-a-configuration-object)